Unable to boot with any new kernel versions- Kernel panic
Whenever I am upgrading Ubunut version on my only Ubunut VM server on Microsoft Hyper-V hosting one of the security product that we use in our organisation, it never boots with new kernel. It neither boots with recovery mode of new kernel. Only the old kernel is able to boot the OS. I have already tried rebuilding the initramfs and updating grub as suggested by some articles but that didn't help even though initramfs image files are created and updated during grub update. Currently we are on 20.04 and even tried 22.04. VM is in generation 1. I am not a linux expert. Appreciate if you guys can help me to solve this problem.
Kernel Panic Error Screenshot
Regards,
Shanavas Abdulrahman
